# lucene index query without key

Tags: lucene

Can we do a lucene query without the key and just providing the value?
For ex:
Lets have index is on created on following two properties, city and country
Now, can i search, "*:query" , without specifying any of the properties name.

Thanks,
Abdul

Answer (score 0):

There is a default field you can configure, but if you want to search both (or all) your data with a single query term, you can create a new field to search, and add all of the data for searching to that field.
So right now you're adding:

```
city: mycity
country: mycountry
```

you could add another field, call it address, or text, something that makes sense for your uses, so we have:

```
city: mycity
country: mycountry
address: mycity mycountry  maybe even some other things too
```

And I could now search 'address' for city, or country, or both with nice ordering by relevance.

You'll want to make sure 'city' and 'country' and stored (Field.Store.YES) so you can fetch them later.  'address' would be just for searching, so make sure it's indexed (Field.Index.ANALYZED), and most likely not stored (Field.Store.NO).  Whether you want to index city and country is up to you, but it probably isn't a bad idea in the case that you DO want to only search for a term as the country.